# The Bosch dishwasher freezes a few hours after resetting a program!

Tags: repair, dishwasher

I have a Bosch dishwasher (SGS69T02) for about 16 years.

Recently, after I reset (soft reset) a program indicated by the two buttons (hold down the two program buttons for three seconds) and then select another program, the dishwasher started the new program correctly and continued until The end of the program works without problems. But after turning it off and turning it on again, a strange thing happens!

The dishwasher model 69t02 has two displays. One is the main screen that you can see in orange color in the photo below, and the other is a small screen on the upper edge of the door, next to the program buttons.

[image]

In normal mode, when the dishwasher is working well, by opening the door, the small display (you can see it in below pic, my dishwasher panel looks almost like this picture) on the top edge lights up and by selecting the program, it shows me the duration (in this case, the main display is off),

[image: My dishwasher panel looks almost like this picture]

Then after closing the door, the front main display turns on and the work continues. But, when the problem I described above occurs, when the dishwasher is turned on, the main screen is turned on instead of the small display and shows the duration of the last program executed and none of the program buttons work, and the dishwasher does not start when the door is closed (freezes).

Of course, it is interesting to know that in this case that the problem has occurred, if you want to make configurations on the dishwasher by holding the program buttons while turning on the dishwasher, it is possible. For example, to adjust the volume of the alarm, you must hold one of the program buttons at the same time when turning on the dishwasher. Well, this is done. But if the dishwasher is turned on in non-configuration mode, the problem remains.

What I have done is as follows:

1. Replacing the dishwasher door latch completely. A full test was also taken with an ohmmeter.
2. Checking the board under the buttons and wiring on the door. No traces of short-circuit or interruptions were seen.
3. Reset by unplug the dishwasher for one hour.
4. Complete scaling with finish tablets.

In order for the dishwasher to return to normal state, it must be unplugged for almost one or two days. After that, the machine will be back to normal state and the machine can be used repeatedly!! But if the soft reset is done again, I will face the same problem.

Where do you think the problem comes from? I feel that the problem is with the main control board, but why does it only appear in this specific mode?

Comment: You're asking us to perform diagnostics on a PC board from the other side of the internet. You realize that's a bit of a tough ask, right? Sadly, appliances these days (since the 80s, if not earlier) are designed to be repaired by replacing components (like a PC board), not by repairing the component itself. If you have followed all the trouble shooting steps in the owner's manual, you're probably at the stage of replacing the main control board to see if that takes care of it. Just buy it from a place with a good return policy in case that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Usually it is something mechanical, like the door switch

Comment: @Ruskes, I changed the door switch. In your opinion, which mechanical part can cause this problem? Which mechanical part do you think is likely to fail?

Comment: Did you do the Factory Reset ?

Comment: @Ruskes, I can't do factory reset. Because in the case of a problem, the buttons no longer work. In old models, two of the device's program buttons must be held simultaneously for 3 seconds to reset the device, and this cannot be done by holding the power button for 3 seconds. Therefore, the only thing I can do is unplugging the dishwasher for two days. It does not reset even in half a day or one day!

Comment: Maybe after 16 years, it is time to retire it.  New ones are more efficient as well.